# How to disable image link after database value reaches a certain number

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I need to know how to disable an image that links members to a "Create" page after they have reached their aloted number of pages for their membership. The PHP code recognizes what membership type they are, which is identified in the mysql database.

I need to know when PRO members reach 20 web pages, and disable the link that takes them to the "Create" page (preferably replacing the image with a different one with a dead link.

There is a specific field in the database that records the count of webpages, based on their membership (FREE Member = 0; PRO Member = 20; ELITE Member = 60).

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: my recommendation is to do this with the PHP code. Don't try it with javascript, as mentioned in your tags. The javascript always can be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without you providing any speicific code - here is a pseudocode answer:

```
$count = get_count_of_webpages_from_database_for_this_user();
if ($count <= function_to_check_for_maximum_count_for_this_user())
{
     echo "live link image/button";
}
else
{
     echo "dead link image/button";
}
```

Comment: Thanks much Laurencei. This basic code helped me figure out what I needed to do.